# How can I send a message to a JLabel from a different class?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a simple alarm clock application in JAVA and I used Matisse to create the GUI.

I have two classes: `Alarm` and `AlarmGUI` and I am trying to get `Alarm` to set the JLabel in `AlarmGUI` that will display the current time. Here is the code:

`Alarm`

```
static String dateLabelGUI = new String();
static String timeLabelGUI = new String();

private static String getTime() {
    DateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    timeLabelGUI = time.format(calendar.getTime());
    return timeLabelGUI;
}

private static String getDate() {
    DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    dateLabelGUI = date.format(calendar.getTime());
    return dateLabelGUI;
}

private static void alarmClock() {
    Timer alarmClock = new Timer();
    TimerTask timer = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
          AlarmGUI aGUI = new AlarmGUI();
          aGUI.setTimeLabel(getTime());
        }
    };
    alarmClock.scheduleAtFixedRate(timer, 0, 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    alarmClock();
    AlarmGUI a = new AlarmGUI();
    a.setVisible(true);
}
```

`AlarmGUI`

```
/** Creates new form AlarmGUI */
public AlarmGUI() {
    initComponents();       
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JMenu alarmMenu;
private javax.swing.JLabel dateLabel;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar menuBar;
private javax.swing.JLabel timeLabel;
// End of variables declaration                   

public void setDateLabel(String aDate){
    dateLabel.setText(aDate);
}

 public void setTimeLabel(String aTime){
    timeLabel.setText(aTime);
}
```

(I have omitted part of the `AlarmGUI` code that it's not relevant).

Basically `alarmClock()` should send a message to `AlarmGUI` to set the relevant JLabel to `timeLabelGUI`, but the label is empty when I run the program and I can't figure out why. Could anybody help with this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you add the JLabels to a JPanel, and add the JPanel to a JFrame?

Comment: JLabels are added directly to the JFrame (The frame is generated by NetBeans).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are creating a brand new alarm GUi each time in the alarmClock method.  You are creating a new Frame that is not visible and the frame that is visible is not receiving updates.  You want to implement the code below that passes your visible constructed gui to the code that updates your label.

```
private static void alarmClock(final AlarmGUI aGUI) {
    Timer alarmClock = new Timer();
    TimerTask timer = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
          aGUI.setTimeLabel(getTime());
        }
    };
    alarmClock.scheduleAtFixedRate(timer, 0, 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    AlarmGUI a = new AlarmGUI();
    alarmClock(a);
    a.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you :)